# Jqplot: append right-aligned text and stack donut chart

Tags: jquery, legend, jqplot, responsive, donut-chart

I modified the Legend table HTML in the Chrome console to show the layout I need below.  I've been trying to find out how to append and right-align some dynamic text (the data value) to the label `td` in the legend, but I haven't found figured it out yet.   [I saw a post here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jqplot-users/sU11mci0aUw) that could work, but I need more detail (*the poster was suggesting an enhancement using objects no longer in the `jqplot.js` file and the link to a plugin is broken*).

I appreciate any help with this.  Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var data = [50, 18, 10];

      var tl_labels = [
        ["Purple"],
        ["Gray"],
        ["light green"]
        
      ];

      var tl_colors = ['#8F2DA3', '#939EA9', '#50E3C2', ];

      var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [data], {
        seriesDefaults: {

          renderer: $.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
          rendererOptions: {
            sliceMargin: 0,
            startAngle: -90,
            showDataLabels: false,
            dataLabels: tl_labels,
            totalLabel: false
          }
        },
        grid: {
          background: '#ffffff',
          drawBorder: false,
          shadow: false
        },
        legend: {
          show: true,
          location: 'ne',
          placement: 'outside',
          background: '#ffffff',
          position: 'relative',
          border: 'none',
          labels: tl_labels
        },


        seriesColors: tl_colors
      });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>


<div id="chart1" style="height:300px;width:350px; "></div>
```

Here are two screenshots for what I am looking for:

[image: appended right-aligned text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out. You can also add another `td` on legend using jquery after plotting the chart.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var data = [50, 18, 10];
        
      var tl_labels = [
        ["Purple<span style='float:right'>20%</span>"],
        ["Gray<span style='float:right'>10%</span>"],
        ["light green<span style='float:right'>5%</span>"]
        
      ];

      var tl_colors = ['#8F2DA3', '#939EA9', '#50E3C2', ];

      var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [data], {
        seriesDefaults: {

          renderer: $.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
          rendererOptions: {
            sliceMargin: 0,
            startAngle: -90,
            showDataLabels: false,
            dataLabels: tl_labels,
            totalLabel: false
          }
        },
        grid: {
          background: '#ffffff',
          drawBorder: false,
          shadow: false
        },
        legend: {
          show: true,
          location: 'ne',
          placement: 'outside',
          background: '#ffffff',
          position: 'relative',
          border: 'none',
          labels: tl_labels,
          
        },


        seriesColors: tl_colors
      });
      $("td.jqplot-table-legend:nth-child(2)","#chart1").width(100)
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>


<div id="chart1" style="height:300px;width:350px; "></div>
```

Comment: thanks, your code works perfect! The thing is, I'm won't be hardcoding the data all the time. So, I don't want to have to hard-code the HTML in the array.   It seems jqPlot only creates two cells -- `<td>`-- per row in the legend by default.  Is there a way to create a 3rd `<td>` from the data in the array so I can right align it **without** hardcoding a `<span>` in the array? JS code: `["purple<span>50%</span>"] ...` CSS: `td.jqplot-table-legend:nth-child(2) span { float:right; }`

Comment: You can either change the `legend` plugin or manipulate the table after it was rendered. e.g. $("tr.jqplot-table-legend","#chart1").each(...append the 3rd td here...)